# Mobile keyboard 'Shift' toggle like functionality using RX.Net

Tags: c#, system.reactive, rx.net

Working on a project where I need to emulate the functionality of the 'Shift' button on mobile keyboards; i.e., when pressed it toggles the shift state to on and then after another key is pressed it returns to off, but when held it remains on while other keys are pressed and only returns off after it is pressed/held again. I had been looking into RX some recently and wanted to give it a go as part of this.

I could use eyes on what I've already got, as I'm sure there is a better way to do it, and even more I have no idea how to go about tracking the 'locked' state. I had the standard toggle working (I thought) but now it seems to be firing twice when either event happens. Here's what I have so far

```
ShiftDown = Observable.FromEventPattern(ShiftBtn, "PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown");
ShiftUp = Observable.FromEventPattern(ShiftBtn, "PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp");

ShiftClickedEvent = ShiftDown.Select(_ => ShiftUp.TakeUntil(Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250))))
            .Switch()
            .StartWith(new object());

ShiftHeldEvent = ShiftDown.Select(_ => Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000)).TakeUntil(ShiftUp))
            .Switch()
            .StartWith(0);

IObservable<bool> ShiftState= Observable.CombineLatest(ShiftClickedEvent, ShiftHeldEvent,  (x, y) => new object())
            .Scan(false, (currentState, z) => !currentState)
            .StartWith(false)
            .DistinctUntilChanged();
```

Just trying to figure out how far off base I am. Appreciate any help.

**EDIT**

Ended up changing gears and handling it a different way. This accomplishes what I wanted to do originally and also makes some other thoughts I had easier to implement. Still open to any suggestions, but here is the new code:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
    ShiftState = Observable.FromEventPattern(ShiftButton, "Click")
        .Select(_ => "shift");
    ShiftHoldState = Observable.FromEventPattern(ShiftButton, "MouseRightButtonDown")
        .Select(_ => "lock");
    CtrlState = Observable.FromEventPattern(CtrlButton, "Click")
        .Select(_ => "ctrl");
    PosState = Observable.FromEventPattern(POSButton, "Click")
        .Select(_ => "pos");

    KeyPress = Observable.Merge(
        FindLogicalChildren<HMKEnglishKey>(this).Select(
            o => Observable.FromEventPattern<RoutedEventHandler, RoutedEventArgs>(
                h => o.Click += h,
                h => o.Click -= h
                )
                .Select(_ => "default")
            ));

    ModState = Observable.Merge(ShiftState, PosState, CtrlState, ShiftHoldState, KeyPress)
            .Scan("default" , (prev, current) => UpdateMods(prev, current))
            .StartWith("default")
            .DistinctUntilChanged();

    TestButton.Init();
}

private string UpdateMods(string prev, string current)
{
    string returnVal =
        (prev == "lock" && current == "default") ? "lock"
        : (prev == "lock" && current == "shift") ? "default"
        : prev == current ? "default" : current;
    return returnVal;
}
```

*Note - It turns out that Windows 10 touch screen holds are considered right mouse clicks, which is why I was able to use that to mimick a long hold. I may still tinker with the old thoughts to make it compatible with mouse but for now it works.

Comment: Isn't `IObservable<bool> ShiftState = ShiftDown.Select(ep => true).Merge(ShiftUp.Select(ep => false));` what you need?

Comment: The Clicked/Held streams fire their events correctly. I had gone with them as independent streams since they should have somewhat different behavior.

Comment: I really don't understand what you mean by either of those two sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up going with a different approach, see revised code in post